# Angular project build issue with Angular Slickgrid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17, angular-slickgrid

I've just migrated my project from Angular 13 to Angular 17 and angular-slickgrid from 4.1.4 to 7.5.0 and I cannot build the project.
I have fixed all errors but one :
Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
ERROR: node_modules/@slickgrid-universal/common/dist/types/interfaces/column.interface.d.ts:6:189 - error TS2322: Type 'Join<R, D>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.efined'.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
ever : string;
6 type Join<T extends any[], D extends string> = T extends [] ? never : T extends [infer F] ? F : T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? F extends string ? string extends F ? string : `${F}${D}${Join<R, D>}` : never : string;

And I don't find the reason of this error

I've check every Column implementation in the project to find a reason (bad description, missing field ...) but every piece of code looks good.
I've tried to downgrade Typescript but no good effect.
I've compared package.json between Latest Angular-Slickgrid-master. Everthing looks the same

Comment: Make sure to follow every [Migration Guide](https://ghiscoding.gitbook.io/angular-slickgrid/migrations/migration-to-5.x) 1 by 1. Also make sure to update all Slickgrid-Universal to the correct version assigned to each Angular-Slickgrid version, see [version compatibility](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Versions-Compatibility-Table). My guess is that you jumped way too fast, you should do 1 Angular/Angular-Slickgrid version at a time but it looks like you jumped straight from 4.x to 7.x and that is not a good idea. You should bump to 5.x, test it, then jump to 6.x...

Comment: I should emphasize again the version compatibility between Angular-Slickgrid and Slickgrid-Universal (see version comp table ref above). I've never found a way to avoid TypeScript throwing interface errors when I bump only Slickgrid-Universal (similar to your question), which is why I always release versions for both on the same day. Internally, the difference is that Angular-Slickgrid extends `GridOption` with some variances for some options and when Universal is bumped without bumping Angular then it throws weird TS interface errors like yours, so review both Angular/Universal versions

Comment: I already have this build error with 4.x version. That's why I tried to migrate it.

Comment: oh wait that's the new TypeScript error that we fixed in this Slickgrid-Universal [PR](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/pull/1427) but I didn't release a new version yet. It's caused by a newer version of TypeScript which is more strict than before, if you downgrade to an older version like `~5.2.x` it will probably work. I'm still working on some things, I'm not sure when I'll have time to push a new version, so please dowgrade TypeScript or click on the error and change the interface in your node_modules with what is in the PR I referenced

Comment: Thank you. It was the problem. Downgraded to ~5.2.2 and everything is building now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, that was an issue that was brought by recent TypeScript version which is a bit more strict than before. We added a fix in Slickgrid-Universal and in Angular-Slickgrid [v7.6.0](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases/tag/v7.6.0) which fixes this issue. I did upgrade TypeScript within Angular-Slickgrid itself and everything seems fine. Give it a try.