# Django, Docker, SlickGrid - Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'slickgrid'

Tags: django, docker, npm, slickgrid

I'm trying to build Django backend based application on Docker using PyCharm with NPM and slickgrid.

When in some .js file trying to import slickgrid:

`import { SlickGrid, SlickDataView } from 'slickgrid';`

I'm getting Django error:

FilterError at /todo/
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'slickgrid' from '/opt/project/eTools/todo/static/todo/js/main.js'

For dealing with Django static assets I use:
django-compressor
django-compressor-toolkit

In Dockerfile I have something like:

`

## Set work directory

WORKDIR /code
(...)
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
(...)
#Slickgrid
RUN npm install -g browserify babelify@8 babel-core babel-preset-env babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
RUN npm install -g slickgrid
(...)

## Copy the Django project

COPY ./eTools/ /code/
`

It looks like npm used indirectly by Django does not see 'slickgrid'.

In bash for Docker I see following:
a) in location where app was copied in last step of Dockerfile (/code/ location) npm has slickgrid:
root@f7401a6daac5:/code# npm list slickgrid
code@ /code
└── slickgrid@5.8.2
b) but for unknown reason (for me at least ;)) npm seems to be called from location from exception ('/opt/project/'). checked in docker bash and there is no 'slickgrid':

root@f7401a6daac5:/opt/project# npm list slickgrid
eTools_root@1.0.0 /opt/project
└── (empty)

Could you please advice how I can fix this issue? And why code is called from another location than /code? Is this related to PyCharm?

Part of Django settings related to compress and static:

```
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'eTools', 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'todo', 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'clients', 'static'),
    'node_modules', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'node_modules/'),
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'js'), #Add global js directory
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
    'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter',
    'compressor.filters.template.TemplateFilter',
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]

COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter',
]

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('module', 'compressor_toolkit.precompilers.ES6Compiler'),
    ('css', 'compressor_toolkit.precompilers.SCSSCompiler'),
)
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_LOCAL_NPM_INSTALL = False
COMPRESS_NODE_MODULES = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'`
```

Thanks!

I tried to follow multiple tutorials and maybe mixed some settings?

Comment: I'm not at all across Django or js build tools, but @ghiscoding gave some information in this answer that might assist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78186878/angular-project-build-issue-with-angular-slickgrid